# Syntax error, even after various fixes on a simple code, this is driving me nuts First line it accuses error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, nodemon

This is driving me nuts, i try to run the code down below on nodemon and everytime, it gives me the
Syntax error number 800A03EA. Can someone help?

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});

client.login('token url is here  i just hide it');
```

Comment: let me put on my magic hat and try to see which line the error is at

Comment: That error code comes from Windows software (meaning VS Code), not Nodemon. That's pretty antiquated error code too, something I would expect to see from JScript or VB Script. Is your editor configured to understand ES2015+, and do you happen to have any oddball unicode characters in your code that didn't come through in the copy-paste?

Comment: Well i have seen a oddball unicode character in line 3 and fixed it.
I still receive the same error, my configuration is not getting ES2015+.
nodemon is ver 2.0.7 maybe have some error of unicode characters yet.

Comment: Found the error is when i execute nodemon i don't call a node code. Now is working properly. Thanks for the help :D